# Show dummy image when property is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I've a little widget that displays some user info

```
<div id="this-is-me">
    <p class="userpic"><img src="/gfx/gui/{{ user.avatar }}" alt="{{ user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name }}" width="75" height="75"></p>
    <h6>{{ user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name }}</h6>
    <ul class="options white right inline">
        <li><a href="#/profile">Profiel bekijken</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

as you can see, the avatar is being rendered, but when the user.avatar is empty this results in a broken link, giving the user a 404 error on the page.

i've tried to add some defaulting logic inside the braces like so `{{ user.avatar || 'missing-user.png' }}`

is there a proper way to fix this in angular?
i can't use ng-switch, as that removes html, and this widget is present on the page before and after login. so if the user logs in, this widget should re-render and still show the avatar... I believe this is not possible with ng-switch as that removes the html and never gets re-rendered.

Comment: have you tried `ng-src` instead of `src`?  Might work with your interpolation example.

Comment: i am afraid but you have to write a directive for this and if you simple dont way 404 just use ng-src

Comment: thanks for the ng-src tip, i'll take a look at that documentation didn't know it existed

Comment: Maybe `ng-show` and `ng-hide` can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use `ng-switch`, please try it here. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4U2qk/4/)

```
<span ng-switch on="!!user.avatar">
    <img ng-switch-when="true" ng-src="/gfx/gui/{{ user.avatar }}" alt="{{ user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name }}" width="75" height="75">
    <img ng-switch-when="false" ng-src="missing-user.png">
</span>

$scope.$apply(function () {
    console.log('done');
    $scope.user.avatar = "XXX";
});
```

The trick is to force to convert the user.avatar object to `Boolean` using `!!` and then the condition will simple be `true` or `false`.

Comment: how does this work when the user.avatar changes? I mean after the user logs in and another route shows his home screen, the directive needs to update and show the other part of the equasion, but your switch statement has removed that html... that doesn't seem all right to me...

Comment: Long story short, it is because of the magic of $apply module.